# P-group of nilpotency class $2$ and Schur multiplier

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $p$ be an odd prime and let $G$ be a p-group of nilpotency class $2$ in which $V=G/G'$ is an elementary abelian p-group. Let $M(V)$ be the Schur multiplier of $V$ which is isomorphic to the exterior square $V\wedge V$.

Is $M(V)$ necessarily isomorphic to $G'$?

If the answer is no, does there exist a p-group $G$ of nilpotency class $2$ in which $V=G/G'$ is an elementary abelian p-group and $M(G)=1$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $V’$ is trivial: if $G$ is nilpotent of class $2$, then $G/G’$ is abelian. Are you asking if $M(V)$ is trivial? Not generally; if $k\geq 2$, then $M(\mathbb{Z}_p^k)\cong \mathbb{Z}_p^{k(k-1)/2}$, if I’m not mistaken.

Comment: In fact, G is non-abelian, else G is of class 1.

Comment: When you say “class two” (as opposed to “class at most 2”), then of course one understand $G$ is nonabelian. But your comment utterly fails to answer my question. Did you really mean to ask whether $M(V)$ is isomorphic to $V’$, which is trivial? Or did you mean to ask if $M(V)$ is isomorphic to $G’$?

Comment: Sorry and thank you for your remark, I see G' is trivial. I mean by my question (the first question) if $M(V)$ is isomorphic to $G'$?

Comment: So, the answer is no. Just note that the commutator of $G$ and $G\times\mathbb{Z}_p$ are equal, but if you add a bunch of direct factors that are copies of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, you. make $G/G’$ have larger and larger rank, thus making $M(V)$ larger and larger, all the while keeping $G’$ the same.

Comment: And, yes, there are groups with trivial Schur multiplier and elementary abelian abelianization. For example, the first isoclinism family listed in Theorem 2.15, page 5 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.11308.pdf).

Comment: Yes thank you very much. Can you put your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the first question is “no”. Note that if $K=G\times C_p$, where $C_p$ is cyclic of order $p$, then $K’=G’$, and $K^{\rm ab}\cong G^{\rm ab}\times C_p$. In particular, if $G$ is of class two and $G^{\rm ab}$ is elementary abelian, then the same holds for $K$, but the rank of $K^{\rm ab}$ is strictly larger than that of $G$. That means that you can make $V\wedge V$ have arbitrarily large rank while not changing the commutator subgroup, so we cannot have that $M(V)$ is necessarily isomorphic to $G’$.

As for an example of a $p$ group $G$ of class two with $G^{\rm ab}$ elementary abelian and with trivial Schur multiplier, the easiest example is the extra-special $p$-group of order $p^3$ that is not of exponent $p$,
$$G = \langle x,y \mid x^{p^2}=y^p=[x,y,x]=[x,y,y]=1, x^p=[x,y]\rangle.$$
The same will hold for any group that is isoclinic to $G$.

The Schur multipliers of the four non-abelian groups of order $p^3$ are known classically; you can also read off that this group has trivial Schur multiplier from Theorem 49 in *Certain homological functors of $2$-generator $p$-groups of class $2$* by A. Magidin and R.F. Morse, in **Computational Group Theory and the Theory of Groups II**, Contemporary Mathematics no. 511, American Mathematical Society, Providence RI, 2010, pp. 127-166. The group above corresponds to the tuple $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma;\rho,\sigma)=(1,1,1;0,1)$ in the notation of Theorem 1 of that paper.